# Adding a new spark-package to scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have been working with the spark-csv package https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv under scala spark. I would like to install the package so that I can access the package functionality without having to use the flag `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0` when running `spark-shell`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the `SPARK_HOME` directory
2. Create or open `conf/spark-defaults.conf`
3. Add `spark.jars.packages` property with a list of required packages separated by comma. For example:

   ```
   spark.jars.packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0,com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.3.1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the package as a dependency under the **libraryDependencies** key in your build.sbt file or to your pom.xml file if your are using maven as your build tool. When you create an uber jar with the sbt-assembly plugin or the maven assembly plugin, the databricks-csv jar is packaged inside the resulting jar. You can then simply use `spark-submit` to run your code without having to use the `--packages` commandline option